# Turn off ssl validation for ansible with_url

Tags: ssl, ansible

I would like to use the following task in my playbook

```
- set_fact:
    md5_value: "{{ item }}"
  with_url: "https://localJenkins/{{platformBuildMd5Url}}"
```

Unfortunately the localJenkins is using self-signed certificate. Is there a way to turn off the ssl validation for with_url?

Comment: Related documentation is here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/lookup/url.html

Does not seem to answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lookup` builtin:

```
- set_fact:
    md5_value: "{{ lookup('url','https://localJenkins/'+platformBuildMd5Url,validate_certs=False) }}"
```